# Anylogic: Accessing variables from simulation menu

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I'm all new to the world of simulation and Anylogic and I can't for the life of me figure out how to access a value from my Simulation menu:

[image]

...and then use it in my **Main** simulation agent.

I'm trying to access `combobox1` to receive its value with `.getValue()`.
How do I gain access to a variable from another agent?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the screenshot below, select your Simulation pane and, in Properties, set the target Parameter in Main (in this case scenarioSLR) to *Control*.getValue() (in this case simulationSLRlevel, the name I gave to the radio button control shown).

[image: screenshot]

Alternatively, AnyLogic recommends using an intermediate variable, as described in this 3-minute YouTube video. https://youtu.be/pd8QMBL-ri4